AndroidUsbCamera_not_working
Is there any official Android library to access an external USB camera?
I have gone through all the Android camera samples, but I couldn't get my external USB camera to be detected or listed with the following code. I also checked other libraries like saki4510t/UVCCamera and jiangdongguo/AndroidUSBCamera, but they are either outdated or not working. The official Android documentation on external USB cameras does not provide a proper way to implement it in Kotlin or Java. I couldn't find the latest documentation on this.

I tried integrating it myself, but it's not working. Here’s the code I used:
private fun requestUsbPermissions() {
        val usbManager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
        val deviceList = usbManager.deviceList
        val deviceIterator = deviceList.values.iterator()
        while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            val device = deviceIterator.next()
            if (!usbManager.hasPermission(device)) {
                val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
                usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
            } else {
                listAvailableCameras()
            }
        }
    }

    private val usbReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == action) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    val device = intent.getParcelableExtra<UsbDevice>(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        device?.let {
                            listAvailableCameras()  // Refresh camera listing
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED == action) {
                requestUsbPermissions()
            } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED == action) {
            }
        }
    }

    private fun listAvailableCameras() {
        try {
            val cameraIdList = cameraManager.cameraIdList
            for (cameraId in cameraIdList) {
                val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
                val facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
                logCameraCharacteristics(characteristics, cameraId)

                if (facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL) {
                    selectedCameraId = cameraId
                    return
                }
            }

            // Default to internal camera
            selectedCameraId = cameraIdList.firstOrNull() ?: throw CameraAccessException(CameraAccessException.CAMERA_ERROR)
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun logCameraCharacteristics(characteristics: CameraCharacteristics, cameraId: String) {
        val facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
        val facingStr = when (facing) {
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT -> "FRONT"
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK -> "BACK"
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL -> "EXTERNAL"
            else -> "UNKNOWN"
        }

        val outputFormats = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)?.outputFormats
        val fpsRanges = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES)

    }

    private fun openCamera(cameraId: String) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return
        }
        try {

            cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    cameraDevice = camera
                    startCameraPreview()
                }

                override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    camera.close()
                }

                override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                    camera.close()
                }
            }, backgroundHandler)
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


This is the error I am getting:
2024-07-01 13:51:09.578 27203-27373 Perf                    com.aditya.androidcamera             E  getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2024-07-01 13:51:09.580 27203-27373 Perf                    com.aditya.androidcamera             E  Fail to get file list com.aditya.androidcamera
2024-07-01 13:51:09.580 27203-27373 Perf                    com.aditya.androidcamera             E  getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2024-07-01 13:51:09.630 27203-27203 AppCompatDelegate       com.aditya.androidcamera             D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2024-07-01 13:51:09.685 27203-27203 a.androidcamer          com.aditya.androidcamera             W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2024-07-01 13:51:09.689 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Listing available cameras...
2024-07-01 13:51:09.690 27203-27203 CameraManagerGlobal     com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Connecting to camera service
2024-07-01 13:51:09.698 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Camera ID: 0, Facing: BACK
2024-07-01 13:51:09.736 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Supported FPS Ranges: [1, 10], [10, 10], [1, 15], [15, 15], [1, 30], [30, 30]
2024-07-01 13:51:09.737 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Supported Output Formats: 256, 34, 35
2024-07-01 13:51:09.739 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Camera ID: 1, Facing: FRONT
2024-07-01 13:51:09.740 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Supported FPS Ranges: [1, 10], [10, 10], [1, 15], [15, 15], [1, 30], [30, 30]
2024-07-01 13:51:09.740 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Supported Output Formats: 256, 34, 35
2024-07-01 13:51:09.740 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Selected internal camera: 0
2024-07-01 13:51:09.787 27203-27376 AdrenoGLES              com.aditya.androidcamera             I  PFP: 0x016ee187, ME: 0x00000000
2024-07-01 13:51:09.788 27203-27376 AdrenoUtils             com.aditya.androidcamera             W  <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:194>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2024-07-01 13:51:09.788 27203-27376 AdrenoUtils             com.aditya.androidcamera             W  <ReadGpuID:218>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2024-07-01 13:51:09.799 27203-27203 MainActivity            com.aditya.androidcamera             I  Opening camera with ID: 0
2024-07-01 13:51:09.803 27203-27203 libc                    com.aditya.androidcamera             E  Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"


Questions:

Is there any official or recommended library to handle USB cameras in Android?

Why isn't my external USB camera being detected or listed with the above code? Am I missing any specific permissions or configurations?

Are there any comprehensive guides or up-to-date libraries for integrating external USB cameras in Android?


